# What’s wrong with my website search function? It is a Bootstrap website with no CMS

Tags: html, search, twitter-bootstrap-3

The website is https://thestripclubhookup.com

When I click on the search and try to type in a two word city, it automatically closes the search box.

What is going on with it? I have tried to figure it out but I have no clue what it could be.

It does this on both mobile and desktop.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the JS snippet for the search function:

```
function goCity() {
var category = document.getElementById("categories").value;
if (category == "clubs") {
    var city = document.getElementById("cities").value; 
    //console.log(city);
    if(city != "Location") {    
        window.location.href = city;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error").classList.add("city-error-style");
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please Choose Location";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem where when they press the space bar in their search and the drop down menu closes, I fixed it by doing the following:

Changing the following line in jquery.nice-select.min.js:

```
if(32==t.keyCode||13==t.keyCode)return s.hasClass("open")?l.trigger("click"):s.trigger("click"),!1
```

to

```
if(32==t.keyCode||13==t.keyCode)return s.hasClass("open")?n.trigger("click"):s.trigger("click"),!1
```